# Very low current fuse (100 µA)

Tags: current-measurement, fuses

I have a very low current PCB which connects to a disposable band aid.
The problem is that I need some sort of way to identify that the band aid has never been used before.
So I though about adding a fuse that I can burn after each use. I am just not sure how to do this, I could not find any fuse that I can burn at such low currents.
There is probably a smarter way to solve this issue, I am just not to familiar.
The band aid is suppose to touch the skin so I cannot raise the current in fear of electrifying.

Comment: With that tiny amount of energy you are not going to find a conventional fuse that does the job. Tell us more about the PCB and what is on it, can't you save it in some kind of memory somewhere?

Comment: could you cause a "short" as the device is disconnected?

Comment: As the dressing is meant to stick to the skin (?) you could try the sort of tamper-evident technology used with private envelopes, a weak part that tears if it's pulled apart with some bit still stuck down. It would indicate either visually, or you could have a conductor running through the tearable region.

Comment: What type (part number) of battery is on the device? Does it have a microprocessor (part number)?

Comment: But how will you know when to burn the "fuse"? How will you recognize when the aid has been used, so as to act accordingly?

Comment: PlasmaHH* - I am afraid adding a memory unit would be a very expensive solution.
Solar Mike- a short is also possible, just though a fuse is closest logical term.
Neil_UK- This is also very, so I asked a mechanical engineering to see what could be the weakpoints of such solution.
nickagian- I though maybe something logical as "If there is a cutoff between the points, the band was used".

Comment: What property of the "band aid" changes once it has been used?

Comment: @Shauli I'm assuming that this band aid is an expendable that is attached to a separate device. You want something cheap on the expendable, but don't mind cost in the attached device. Plus, because human contact is involved it must be low voltage, low current, no charge storage to speak of, etc. Is that about right? (I'm asking because I was involved in a temperature measuring device using during heart operations and ZERO current and ZERO voltage was a benefit we achieved that gave us something the competition couldn't reach.

Comment: @Jonk, Something like that, I guess what I am doing is a bit more amateur. I am very intrigued.

Comment: @Shauli I'd be looking first for an optical means to achieve your goal. First off, "E-Ink" is around now and used in displays. You should be able to find a source of this at very low cost (and they operate with extremely tiny currents.) These are switchable and nonvolatile. And you only need ONE DOT. Not a whole display. Or look up flip-dot/flip-disc stuff. Or you could examine the polymers used in writable CD/DVD (I personally worked on the first rewritable CD "back in the day") which use dyes that absorb at certain wavelengths. Lots and lots of optical approaches to this problem pop to mind.

Comment: @Shauli In the polymer case, there are NO CURRENTS, NO VOLTAGES, at all. It's all done with tiny, cheap lasers and laser dyes added to cheap polymers. You don't even need to actually read tiny dots separately, so you don't need all the focusing crap we had to go through. The first rewritable CD?? We "erased" it by putting it in a toaster oven. Seriously. Heat relaxed the polymer back to its nominal state. Laser light reversed that effect, causing a "write." But on the first disks this was not erasable using laser light (way too slow, sadly.) So we just popped them in a toaster oven.

Comment: Sounds amazing, I am going to read about it rightnow.
Thanks!!

Comment: Hey @jonk, I am having a hard time in finding information about the digital ink solution. My problem is that there aren't any articles about how exactly the scanner is working or how to print the identification/barcode on the disposable itself.
Thanks,
Shauli

Answer (score 3):

I can't directly help you with a method, but there are a number of medical "disposables" that time out and cannot be reused.  I believe attachments for the DaVinci surgical robot work this way.  You're having what we call an "XY problem".  You're not really looking for a fuse, you're looking for a way to identify a disposable that has already been used, presumably via electronic means, presumably low cost, and presumably with some realistic interface requirements that you haven't shared.  You'll get a much better answer if you spend the time speccing out your real problem than walking us into the middle of it.

A variety of approaches may work.  Anything that would provide a read-only unique ID on the bandaid would allow you to maintain a database on your host device, and you can then upload to some central database if necessary.    Microchip has a unique ID product at $0.17 USD in 5K quantity: http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/24AA02UID   -- I'm sure there are many competitors

In fact, any small writable memory device on the bandaid would allow you to set a "used" bit by some circumspect method.  This might even be more difficult to build a work around for than a "fuse" which can always be mechanically shorted.

Comment: Hey there, my problem with the band aid is not that someone is going to bypass it on purpose. I just want to disable the option to reuse by mistake as it is no longer sterile. There are no hidden requirements. I am just not sure what information is relevant as I am not so sure what is the best solution. Just trying to get a grip if it is even plausible.

Comment: @Shauli -- same approach would be necessary.  Note that commercial bandaids acheive the same result by printing "contents no longer sterile if opened".  This is largely the same for surgical packs, except that they don't bother printing the warning.  In fact, you don't have to use the bandaid to make it non sterile, just open the packaging, so the fuse approach is not effective.

Comment: The warning are not enough from our experience. There are attempts to reuse the band-aid to save money.
Isn't there some sort of capacitor or transistor that I can burn at 100microA? Is that even logical to do something like this?
Thanks for the help btw.

Comment: Not that I can think of.  I can envision a system where removing the bandaid rips a resistance wire leaving it open, but that's a mechanical solution.

Comment: Are you certain that there is an issue with re-use if you clearly mark the packaging, and use an obvious anti tamper seal? I work in medical devices, we do this all the time. Medical professionals are *very* good about not reusing stuff that's not supposed to be reused. It's actually a serious reportable event if they don't (extreme example: needle re-use causing cross contamination). Just place a seal on it, and mark the package with the international standard single use medical device symbol (a "2" in a circle with a line through it).

Comment: @PeterK -- are you asking me, or the OP?

Comment: The OP, @Shauli. Sorry, should have clarified.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't really understood your problem. Or put it otherwise, I don't understand how a "fuse" will solve you the problem. What I don't get is how will you recognize it is time to burn the "fuse"? And how are you going to burn it?

But anyway, one idea is that you could use a small microcontroller with a flash (either integrated or external) and an external switch (for example a FET).

When you want the electronic to be "dead", you could set a bit flag in the flash. Each time the microcontroller boots, it will have to read this bit and if it is set then it will not close the switch. Otherwise it should allow current to the circuit.

Comment: Hey Nick,
What I thought of is creating a test that can validate the integrity of the fuse. I mean if the fuse is burnt, we have a cutoff, so no current can. Lets say that I compare that current before the fuse and after the fuse and if they are not matching than I can assume the fuse is burnt and the band aid has been used.
Thanks for the answer!

Comment: That's all nice what you describe, but I still don't get it! :-) You now speak of how you will understand that the aid has been used. But when will the fuse be burnt? At what moment? And how?

Comment: When the user turns off the device I guess, "the how" is a big problem, the fuse is just a concept and that's why I'm asking what is possible to be done in the situation :).

Comment: That's what I thought. I that case I think the solution I proposed could indeed work.

Comment: I will try to research some more about your solution. I hope it won't be too difficult to execute.